# After copying Laravel from one PC to another it shows a strange error from helpers.php

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

When I copied the laravel folder from one PC to another and tried to run it, it shows the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php
>   on line 383

The same file is working well in the source PC, but in the destination PC it is not.

I have googled it, but no help.

So I tried to make it online. Even though I have changed the name of the database in `database.php` file in the production server it takes the old database only.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On other PC you have PHP < 5.4.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

So, most probably, on line 383 you have an array with new `[]` syntax.

Solution is to upgrade PHP, PHP 5.3 is not supported anymore: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: the other PC cant available right now. i will check